# FtpWebRequest progress not reporting correctly

Tags: c#

I can not figure out how to pull progress accurately on a FtpWebRequest instance, a file transfer.

I have added the Invoke line to interact with the progressbar, no matter what it comes to say, if the file is 74MB then the progress reports 74% when completed. This should be 100%.

I cant figure it out, I tried different things, but never stays consistant with the bytes and the final result to 100%.

My code

```cs
public void DownloadFile(string host, string filename, string username, string password)
{
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"ftp://" + host.Trim() + "/" + filename.Trim());

    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

    using Stream ftpStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
    using Stream fileStream = File.Create(@".\Test\" + filename);

    int filesize = 77987378; // 74MB example
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];

    int read;
    progressBar1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => progressBar1.Maximum = filesize));

    while ((read = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        progressBar1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => progressBar1.Value = (int)fileStream.Position));
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Also... why are you using `FtpWebRequest`? It's one of the worst designed parts of the .NET standard library, imo.

Comment: Post corrected. It is just a user control that adds a progressbar to a listview. It updates using a method and works perfectly for everything else, except this.

Comment: The bug is that you're only updating `progressBar1` after a successful `ftpStream.Read` - but when you reach the end of the stream you never set `progressBar1.Value = 100`

Comment: Would I check and establish this in the while loop or after the block?

Comment: And absolutely noted - I will look for better client code if this is outdated - I am on .NET Framework 4.8 by choice

Answer (score 0):

Close, but no cigar - you're missing a *single* line.

- Also, methinks wrap `progressBar1.Invoke` for simpler call-sites (see `SetProgress` below).
- And use `Int64`, not `Int32`, to represent file sizes, as any file sized over 2GiB will cause it to overflow.

```
public void DownloadFile(string host, string filename, string username, string password)
{
    // ...

    this.progressBar1.Invoke( () => progressBar1.Maximum = 100 ); // why complicate things?

    Int64 totalBytes           = 77987378; // 74MB example
    Int64 totalBytesDownloaded = 0;

    this.SetProgress( 0, totalBytes );

    while ( ( read = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length ) ) > 0 )
    {
        totalBytesDownloaded += read;

        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        this.SetProgress( totalBytesDownloaded, totalBytes );
    }

    if( totalBytesDownloaded != totalBytes ) throw new InvalidOperationException( "This should never happen." );

    this.SetProgress( totalBytesDownloaded, totalBytes ); // i.e. 100%
}

private void SetProgress( Int64 totalBytesDownloaded, Int64 totalBytes )
{
    Double num  = (Double)totalBytesDownloaded;
    Double den  = (Double)totalBytesDownloaded;
    Double frac = num / den; // i.e. `0...1.0`
    Double perc = frac * 100d; // i.e. `0...100`

    this.progressBar1.Invoke( () => progressBar1.Value = (Int32)perc );
}
```

Comment: I can not get this working, just no value out to the progressbar - so 0% always. I appreciate the time you took on this.

Comment: What happens if you use `Debug.WriteLine` instead of updating `this.progressBar1`, just to see what the values are?

Comment: The answer was Fluent FTP library with async/progress delegates. Thanks for the reply!